# How can I position a Window using SetWindowPos?

Tags: .net

I am using the below code to show a new window next to the Excel work area. It all works fine, but I wanted the new window to be on the left side. I tried changing X in the SetWindowPos but it still loads at the right side. Can someone help here

```
SafeNativeMethods.SetWindowPos(this.SiblingWindow, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, newWidth, siblingRect.Height, SafeNativeMethods.SWP_NOMOVE | SafeNativeMethods.SWP_NOZORDER);
```

> Where

1. this.SiblingWindow is the handle of Excel Workarea
2. newWidth = Excel Workarea.Width - New Window.Width

[image]

Comment: No, Excel stays in control over arranging its child windows.  Quite unclear how that gray panel got created in the first place, but odds you can get it on the left are not great.